# agGrid - How to hide dynamically generated column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In React agGrid `hide: true` in dynamically generated column definition is not working. My code snippet as below:

```js
if(data.length > 0) {
  for (var key in data[0]) {
      var obj = {}
      obj.headerName = key;
      obj.field = key;
      if(obj.field == "action") {
          obj.hide = true;
          obj.suppressToolPanel = true;
      }
      cols.push(obj);
  }
}

root.setState({
  columnDefs: cols,
  rowData : data
}, function(){
  console.log(root.state.columnDefs)
});
```

And my agGrid in render function is as below:

```js
<AgGridReact
  columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
  rowData={this.state.rowData}
  context={this.state.context}
  modules={this.state.modules}
  sideBar={this.state.sideBar}
  defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
  frameworkComponents={this.state.frameworkComponents}
  onGridSizeChanged={this.onGridSizeChanged.bind(this)}
  onCellClicked={this.onCellClicked.bind(this)}
  onFirstDataRendered={this.onFirstDataRendered.bind(this)}
  onGridReady={this.onGridReady.bind(this)}
>
</AgGridReact>
```

Am I missing something? Any help will be very much helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to update the column state is to use [`ColumnApi.setColumnState()`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-state/#column-state)

Also note that:

- AgGrid version < 24: use `ColumnApi.setColumnState()`
- AgGrid version >= 24: use `ColumnApi.applyColumnState()`

```js
const columnState = columnApi.getColumnState() || [];

columnApi.setColumnState(
  columnState.map((c) => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
      return { ...c, hide: true };
    }
    return { ...c, hide: false };
  })
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit gallant-hooks-w8f9y]

Comment: But I want the table to be displayed with few columns hidden by default, not after some button click.

Comment: @KOUSIKMANDAL put the code in the `onGridReady` callback. My live demo has already covered that, the button is only there to demonstrate how you can update the column state programmatically.